# Create MongoDB view using aggregation pipeline operators and python code

Tags: python, mongodb, view, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to create a MongoDB view for a collection using not only aggregation pipeline operators, but also custom Python code for some transformations? Under [MongoDB Views Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) I could not find anything on the topic.

Edit for further clarification of the question: I am dealing with a database collection in which the documents have a certain schema which I cannot change. I need to provide a view on the data in those documents, processing it in some ways. However, the processing steps are too complicated to achieve by using only MongoDB operators. My question revolves around adding a stage to the pipeline which processes the documents in a custom manner, specified by e.g. a Python function.

Comment: no, it's not possible. If you elaborate why you need it there might be other ays to achieve your goals.

Comment: @AlexBlex would it be using JavaScript or sth else or definitely out of question?

Comment: Nothing but the pipeline operators. Any other language would require an environment to run the code.

Comment: Could you elaborate further on what you're trying to do ?